# MongoDB + PHP: support for SSL?

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl

Does the `PHP` client for `MongoDB` have support for `SSL`? Or is there a way to connect to MongoDB instance running in SSL?

I see in MongoDB docs that the client list does not specify for PHP ([this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#ssl-configuration-for-clients)) but I am curious to see if anyone out there have tried or trying and to get an idea of the expected release etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PHP driver supports this in the latest versions. In the connection string you should be able to add the `"ssl"` option like in the following two ways:

1. `$m = new MongoClient( 'mongodb://localhost/?ssl=true' );`
2. `$m = new MongoClient( 'mongodb://localhost', array( 'ssl' => true ) );`

Comment: I've added it: http://news.php.net/php.doc.cvs/11538 It will take some time to show up online though.